# Compile all data produced by rolling regression into one

Tags: r, compilation, regression, rolling-computation

I am doing a rolling regression with a huge database, and the reference column used for rolling is called "Q" with the value from 5 to 45 for each data block. At first I tried with simple codes step by step, and it works very good:

```
fit <- as.formula(EB~EB1+EB2+EB3+EB4)
#use the 20 Quarters data to do regression
model<-lm(fit,data=datapool[(which(datapool$Q>=5&datapool$Q<=24)),])
#use the model to forecast the value of next quarter
pre<-predict(model,newdata=datapool[which(datapool$Q==25),])
#get the forecast error
error<-datapool[which(datapool$Q==25),]$EB -pre
```

The result of the code above is:

```
> head(t(t(error)))
        [,1]
21   0.006202145
62  -0.003005097
103 -0.019273856
144 -0.016053012
185 -0.025608022
226 -0.004548264
```

The datapool has the structure below:

```
> head(datapool)
  X  Q            Firm         EB       EB1        EB2        EB3
1 1  5 CMCSA US Equity 0.02118966 0.08608825 0.01688180 0.01826571
2 2  6 CMCSA US Equity 0.02331379 0.10506550 0.02118966 0.01688180
3 3  7 CMCSA US Equity 0.01844747 0.12961955 0.02331379 0.02118966
4 4  8 CMCSA US Equity         NA         NA 0.01844747 0.02331379
5 5  9 CMCSA US Equity 0.01262287 0.05622834         NA 0.01844747
6 6 10 CMCSA US Equity 0.01495291 0.06059339 0.01262287         NA
       ...
       Firm B(also from Q5 to Q45)
       ...
       Firm C(also from Q5 to Q45)
```

The errors produced above are all marked with "X" value in "datapool", so I can know from which firm does the error come from.

Since I need to run the regression for 21 times (quarters 5-24,6-25,...,25-44), so I do not want to do it manully, and have thought out the following codes:

```
fit <- as.formula(EB~EB1+EB2+EB3+EB4)
for (i in 0:20){
model<-lm(fit,data=datapool[(which(datapool$Q>=5+i&datapool$Q<=24+i)),])
pre<-predict(model,newdata=datapool[which(datapool$Q==25+i),])
error<-datapool[which(datapool$Q==25),]$EB -pre
}
```

The codes above works, and no error come out, but I do not know how to compile all errors produced by each regression into one datapool automatically? Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: The problems with this code are that the 'error' (really, really bad name) object is not pre-allocated and then it's also not indexed. You are always overwriting "error" with the last result. You should also say what you will be doing with the results.

Comment: @DWin Thanks for the answer. I need to analyse the distribution of the errors for different peer firms(firms with similar characteristics) in order to do further research. With the stepwise Code, the error was produced correctly. But i need to run the code 21 times to get the 21 error-set, and then use rbind() to append 21 error-set, however it is not so efficient.  what i want to do now is to do the procedure with a loop, and then append the error-set automatically into one big error-set.

Comment: You don't seem to be reading for meaning. Every time through the loop, the code `error <- ...` will replace any prior value of 'error'.

Comment: @DWin i´m considering to use "ldply(error_,rbind)" but as you said, the error was always overwritten and i only get the last error set. Yes, you are right, i realise my problem here, and trying to figure it out, however til now haven´t find some solution to keep all the Error Set

Comment: Use indexing, standard CS strategy. `for( i in seq_set) err_set[i] <- ...`

Comment: @DWin thanks for the tip. do you mean using     for( i in seq_set) err_set[i] <- ...   within the loop? Could you kindly please explain more detailed about it, i did´t get what you mean:)

Answer (score 0):

(I say again: Really bad idea to use the name 'error' for a vector.) It is the name of a core function. This is how I would have attempted that task. (Using the subset parameter and indexing than the tortured which statements.

```
fit <- as.formula(EB~EB1+EB2+EB3+EB4)
pre <- numeric(len=21)
errset <- numeric(len=21)
for (i in 0:20){
     model<-lm(fit,data=datapool, subset= Q>=5+i & Q<=24+i )
     pre[i]<-predict(model,newdata=datapool[ datapool[["Q"]] %in% i:(25+i), ])
     errset[i]<-datapool[25+i,]$EB -pre
}
errset
```

No gaurantees this won't error out by running out tof data at the beginning or end since you have not offered either data or a comprehensive description of the data-object.

Comment: thank you very much for your effort and help, but i still cannot automatic the procedure. The code returns only 21 errors, not 21 error-set. Anyway i need to go on doing the analysis,can´t spend too much time on the codes. I have made it step by step, and it takes not too much time either. Thanks for your patient and nice tips and help:)